# Getting "Array out of bound exception" Error while running mapreduce in cloudera VM

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run my first word count on Cloudera VM. I am getting the

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at new_pack.word.main(word.java:52)
```

this error on line:

```
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
```

in the driver class.

I have copied the code mentioned in this Cloudera [tutorial](https://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/HadoopTutorial/CDH4/Hadoop-Tutorial/ht_wordcount1_source.html?scroll=topic_5_1).

Comment: did you pass any command line args?

Answer (score 1):

As noted at https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/other/tutorial/CDH5/topics/ht_usage.html in step 5, you'll need to run the job with command-line arguments specifying where to find the input files and where to write the output:

```
$ hadoop jar wordcount.jar org.myorg.WordCount /user/cloudera/wordcount/input /user/cloudera/wordcount/output
```